# Tweaking Dijkstra's Algorithm to detect minimum length cycle in directed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, greedy

I am trying to find the minimum length cycle in a directed graph but this time using a **greedy** algorithm.

I think the smartest way to do it is using Dijkstra's Algorithm  using some kind of tweak. (I also know that the Graph has positive weights which makes it a bit obvious), but I can't seem to be able to find a nice way to do it.

I thought of probably splitting a node into its ingoing and outgoing edges, and running Dijkstra's algorithm for every node like this, which ends up being O(V^3). Can I do better using another greedy algorithm maybe?

Comment: [Here's a quick summary of the state of the art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd–Warshall_algorithm#Comparison_with_other_shortest_path_algorithms). Repeated Dijkstra's *can* be faster than O(V^3) if you use a Fibonacci heap, and E is much smaller than V^2. Otherwise, using Floyd-Warshall is the easy O(V^3) solution.

Comment: @user3386109 Using Floyd-Warshall's not allowed, as I am allowed to use greedy algorithms (and this being a dynamic programming algorithm). Thanks for your suggestion however!

Answer (score 0):

- remove all leaf nodes ( nodes with only in edges ) since they cannot be part of a cycle
- remove all root nodes ( nodes with only out edges ) since they cannot be part of a cycle
- start a breadth first search from every remaining node
- increment depth of each search by one ( easy optimization using threads on a multi-processor machine )
- first search to revisit starting node is the minimum length cycle

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can this be considered a greedy algorithm? If yes, can you explain why, because the greedy part is not really visible to me?